# How to cat and print formatted more than one file?

Tags: command-line, bash, cat

I have a device in `/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/`, and device has lots of files such as `in_current0_raw`, `in_current0_mean_raw`, `in_current0_scale` ...
I want to print them periodically in terminal.
What I tried is not working:

```
#!/bin/bash

DEVICE_PATH=/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/
CMD=$(cat ${DEVICE_PATH}in_current0_raw)

watch -n 1 printf '%-20s: %4.10f' "in_current0_raw" "cat ${DEVICE_PATH}in_current0_raw"
```

It prints:

```
%4.10f              :in                  :cat                 :/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_current0_mean_raw:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `watch` runs commands in a shell, so you need to quote things twice, or use the `-x` switch (if you're not relying on shell syntax). However, it looks like you want to run `cat ...` periodically and use its output as an argument for `printf`, in which case you should use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution). That means you can't use `-x`, but instead will have to single quote that command substitution for the outer shell, and let `watch`'s invocation of the shell take care of it. Something like:

```
watch 'printf "%-20s: %4.10f" "in_current0_raw" "$(cat "${DEVICE_PATH}/in_current0_raw")"'
```

However, this means that `DEVICE_PATH` will be expanded by a different shell, so it should be exported before you run `watch`:

```
export DEVICE_PATH
watch 'printf "%-20s: %4.10f" "in_current0_raw" "$(cat "${DEVICE_PATH}/in_current0_raw")"'
```